# How do I print the key along with the value in JQ?

Tags: json, jq

For example, if I have the data below

```
{
    "test1": {
        "name": "John"
    },
    "test2": {
        "name": "Jack"
    },
    "test3": {
        "name": "Jim"
    },
    "test4": {
        "name": "John"
    }
}
```

and I wanted to get all the items where the name property is John, in the following format

```
{
    "test1": {
        "name": "John"
    },
    "test4": {
        "name": "John"
    }
}
```

How would I go about doing this? If I use the following JQ command: `.[] | select(.name | ascii_downcase | contains("john"))` it only returns

```
{
  "name": "John"
}
{
  "name": "John"
}
```

omitting the keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep original structure, use map_values :

```
map_values(select(.name | ascii_downcase | contains("john")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the update operator `|=` to (un)select each item while keeping the outer context:

```bash
jq '.[] |= select(.name | ascii_downcase | contains("john"))'
```

```json
{
  "test1": {
    "name": "John"
  },
  "test4": {
    "name": "John"
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Kfrpx8fPmMj)